# How do i detect background color change when user draw a custom painter over the widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried searching Google and i all found is how to get color pixels from Image. Which is different from my case. And can be solved by using this plugin : https://pub.dev/packages/image_pixels so that's not my question.

[image]

I'm working on a page where User will have a little mini-game or clear their screen with their fingers. The screen will have to turn completely white in order to complete the test. Basically 'erase' all the color from current page.

[image]

My problem is i have no idea how to detect the white color that user will drawn and overlay the initial background. I found some old thread like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67549600/flutter-how-to-check-if-canvas-is-completely-filled-with-paint) in Google which share a similar issue, but noone answered him so i'm actually not sure if this is even possible.

I did looked into creating the eraser object, however i ran into an issue where BlendMode.clear will simply not work and i don't know why. I don't want to get the color pixels from the Offset position. I want to write a condition to check whether or not the whole page turned completely white.

Here's my CustomPainter code.

```
class ScreenCheckPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final List<Sketch> points;

  ScreenCheckPainter({required this.points});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
      ..strokeWidth = 65.0
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;

    canvas.saveLayer(Rect.largest, Paint());

    for (Sketch sketch in points) {
      final point = sketch.points;

      final path = Path();
      path.moveTo(point.first.dx, point.first.dy);

      for (int i = 0; i < point.length - 1; ++i) {
        final p0 = point[i];
        final p1 = point[i + 1];

        path.quadraticBezierTo(
          p0.dx,
          p0.dy,
          (p0.dx + p1.dx) / 2,
          (p0.dy + p1.dy) / 2,
        );
        canvas.drawCircle(point[i], 10, paint..color = Colors.white);
      }

      canvas.drawPath(path, paint..color = Colors.white);
    }
    canvas.restore();
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(ScreenCheckPainter oldDelegate) {
    return oldDelegate.points != points;
  }
}
```

This is my UI code.

```
class ScreenCheckPage extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const ScreenCheckPage({super.key});

  @override
  ConsumerState<ConsumerStatefulWidget> createState() =>
      _ScreenCheckPageState();
}

class _ScreenCheckPageState extends ConsumerState<ScreenCheckPage> {
  final List<Offset> points = <Offset>[];

  Offset localPos = const Offset(-1, -1);

  @override
  Widget build(
    BuildContext context,
  ) {
    Widget buildCurrentPath(BuildContext context, GetSketch currentSketch,
        GetSketchList currentListSketch) {
      int _pointers = 0;
      var countdown = ref.watch(testCountdownProvider);

      return GestureDetector(
        onPanDown: (details) {
          final box = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
          final offset = box.globalToLocal(details.localPosition);

          setState(
            () {
              localPos = details.localPosition;
              currentSketch.updateCurrentSketch(Sketch(points: [offset]));
              _pointers++;
            },
          );

          //debugPrint(currentSketch.currentSketch.toString());
        },
        onPanUpdate: (details) {
          final box = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
          final offset = box.globalToLocal(details.localPosition);
      

          final points =
              List<Offset>.from(ref.read(getSketchProvider)?.points ?? [])
                ..add(offset);

          setState(
            () {
              localPos = details.localPosition;
              currentSketch.updateCurrentSketch(Sketch(points: points));
              _pointers--;
            },
          );

          //debugPrint(currentSketch.currentSketch.toString());
        },
        onPanEnd: (details) {
          setState(
            () {
              currentListSketch
                  .updateCurrentListSketch(ref.read(getSketchProvider)!);
            },
          );
        },
        child: IgnorePointer(
          ignoring: _pointers > 1,
          child: _pointers > 1
              ? null
              : SizedBox(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: CustomPaint(
                  isComplex: true,
                  willChange: true,
                  painter: ScreenCheckPainter(
                    points: ref.read(getSketchProvider) == null
                        ? []
                        : [ref.read(getSketchProvider)!],
                  ),
                  child: Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
        ),
      );
    }

    Widget buildAllPath(BuildContext context, GetSketchList currentListSketch) {
      return SizedBox(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: CustomPaint(
          foregroundPainter: ScreenCheckPainter(
            points: ref.read(getSketchListProvider),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

    final GetSketch currentSketch = ref.watch(getSketchProvider.notifier);
    final GetSketchList currentListSketch =
        ref.watch(getSketchListProvider.notifier);

    return RepaintBoundary(
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          const Image(
            image: AssetImage("assets/design/ambercolor.png"), 
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            height: double.infinity,
            width: double.infinity,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
          ),
          buildAllPath(context, currentListSketch),
          buildCurrentPath(context, currentSketch, currentListSketch),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is my Riverpod state code.

```
@riverpod
class GetSketch extends _$GetSketch {
 Sketch? _currentSketch;
 Sketch? get currentSketch => _currentSketch;

 @override
 Sketch? build() {
   return currentSketch;
 }

 void updateCurrentSketch(Sketch newSketchPos) {
   state = newSketchPos;
 }

 Sketch? getCurrentSketch() {
   return state;
 }
}

@riverpod
class GetSketchList extends _$GetSketchList {
 final List<Sketch> _currentListSketch = [];
 List<Sketch> get currentListSketch => _currentListSketch;

 @override
 List<Sketch> build() {
   return currentListSketch;
 }

 void updateCurrentListSketch(Sketch newSketchData) {
   state = [...state, newSketchData];
 }

 List<Sketch> getListOfSketch() {
   
   return state;
 }
}
```

Forgot one thing, Model code.

```
class Sketch {
 final List<Offset> points;

 Sketch({required this.points});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, After a few days. I manage to find my answer. Might be a bit of a hack but it worked nicely. So i'm gonna leave it here for everyone in the future.

I read [this article](https://salmanbediya.medium.com/take-screenshot-of-any-widget-programmatically-in-flutter-2bf13e9a048d) and modified the code a bit. So instead of getting the screenshot. I simply get the value of rawRgba from a Future method.

```
Future<Uint8List> readSnapshot() async {
  final GlobalKey _globalkey = GlobalKey();
  RenderRepaintBoundary boundary =
      _globalkey.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderRepaintBoundary;
  ui.Image img = await boundary.toImage();
  ByteData? bytes = await img.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.rawRgba);
  Uint8List memoryImageData = bytes!.buffer.asUint8List();
  return memoryImageData;
}
```

The function above will read the data from GlobalKey. Which i put it inside buildAllPath method. That mean it will directly capture the colored screen along with my white color path.

```
Widget buildAllPath(
  BuildContext context,
  GetSketchList currentListSketch,
  ImgDetails img,
) {
  return SizedBox(
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    child: RepaintBoundary(
      key: _globalkey,
      child: CustomPaint(
        foregroundPainter: ScreenCheckPainter(
            points: ref.read(getSketchListProvider),
            backgroundImage: img.uiImage),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

And decode it back to bytes data type of 'RawRgba'. The value inside bytesdata is a gigantic list of int from buildAllPath range from 0-255. Which i assume represent every color on the screen. All i need to do then is check if every element inside this huge list or atleast most of them are returning 255 (white).

```
///Delayed is needed if you use GestureDetector. 
///And DO NOT PUT THIS INSIDE onPanUpdate. 
///IT WILL KILL YOUR APP'S PERFORMANCE. PUT THEM IN onPanEnd.

      var result = await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 10)).then((_) => readSnapshot());
      var currentAmouth = result.where((element) => element == 255).length;
      var totalAmouth = (WidgetsBinding.instance.platformDispatcher.views
                  .first.physicalSize.width *
              WidgetsBinding.instance.platformDispatcher.views.first
                  .physicalSize.height) * 4;
      var percentage = (currentAmouth / totalAmouth) * 1000;
```

I'd love to hear everyone's though on this one as i'm not really sure if this will hurt the app's performance in a long run.